# firefox sdk: problems including jquery.flot, error says dimension height null

Tags: javascript, flot, firefox-addon-sdk

So I'm using the jQuery.flot library and I get this `Invalid dimensions for plot, widht = 700, height = 0` error. So I tried setting the height in javascript before doing the plot and I get a new error `options is null`

Anyone knows what could be the source of that?

Here's my `main.js`:

```
tabs.open({
    url: "./stats.html",
    onReady: function(tab) {
        tab.attach({
            contentScriptFile: [
                "./jquery-2.1.3.min.js",
                "./jquery.flot.min.js",
                "./jquery.flot.pie.min.js",
                "./scripts.js"
            ],
            contentScriptOptions: {
                'logs': ss.storage.logs
            }
        })
    }
})
```

and in my `script.js`:

```
$('#today_pie').width('100%').height('500px')
$.plot('#today_pie', data, {
    series: {
        pie: {
            innerRadius: 0.5,
            show: true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone ever encounter the same problem. I solved it by switching to Chart.js: https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js

it's in html5 and use canvas so maybe that's why it's working.